# is there a tool like phabricator for nodejs applications?

Tags: node.js, phabricator

Is there a tool that we can use that is like phabricator for code reviews for nodejs applications?

I am looking to improve our code review process.

Comment: Why can't you review nodejs code in Phabricator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was said previously, Phabricator can totally handle any type of project for your code review, and offers some really cool feature for code review like pre and post-push code review.

On a side note, the platform I would recommend for code review highly depends on your current setup, mainly how is hosted your git repositories.

If you are looking for other code review platforms I could mention Gitlab and reviewboard.